# How to distribute a complex task using publish/subscribe and a message queue such as Kafka in Java?

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, distributed, publish-subscribe

How would you code the most basic publish/subscribe with Kafka or any dumb queue in the following scenario?

I have a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) with a list of tasks to be done in a specific order. Doing any given task is implemented as a class in Java called Processor. So if there are 10 possible tasks I have 10 processors.

Each processor is one method accepting an input and producing an output. The challenge is performance. On 1 PC, processing terabytes of data can be slow. To improve performance, I want to use multiple PCs.

The best way to distribute processors is to make each processor listen over the network on whichever PC it is running. To do that, I use publish/subscribe which is a feature of almost any message queue.

For example, one processor can be called JoinComplexTableToData and another processor can be DetectAnomalyInData.

I understand I can write the app once and then run multiple instances of it, each on a different PC, listening on the network for input to process and returning the response.

But I do not understand how to use publish/subscribe to make for example 5 PCs do the computation using their resources. All 5 PCs need to use the same distributed message queue such as Kafka for example. The queue needs to contain the data for these PCs in such a way that a complex task with 10 processors can be computed faster on the 5 PCs than if it ran on 1 PC. For example each PC would receive 2 things to do on the queue and it would forward the result to other PCs using the queue so that they pick it up and then they forward their result until everything is done and the final response is picked up from the queue by the PC that has placed the initial request.

So, how is this done? I already have processors and everything else working on a single PC without the message queue yet. On a single PC it is synchronous, one processor has to finish in order for another processor to start. With the distributed message queue I guess the solution will be something with multiple topics/channels.

Advise is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use something out-of-the-box like Hadoop?

Comment: yes, a general purpose big data processing tool such as Hadoop is too "heavy". I require a very lean solution coded in Java, no more than 3000 LOC. The solution I've built already works, only is not yet distributed. Hence, the advice is about something simple and basic with a message queue such as pub/sub + master/slave perhaps? There must be some tutorial or a working example with maybe up to 1000LOC. Or an explanation / suggestion how to get there would help too.